# function returning - unique_ptr VS passing result as parameter VS returning by value

Tags: c++

In c++, what the preferred/recommended way to create an object in a function/method and return it to be used outside the creation function's scope?

In most functional languages, ***option 3** (and sometimes even **option 1**)* would be preferred, but what's the **c++ way** of best handling this?

**Option 1 (return unique_ptr)**

- **pros**: function is pure and does not change input params
- **cons**: is this an unnecessarily complicated solution?

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> createSometing(){
    auto s = std::make_unique<SomeClass>();
    return s;
}
```

**Option 2 (pass result as a reference parameter)**

- **pros**: simple and does not involve pointers
- **cons**: input parameter is changed (makes function less pure and more unpredictable - the ***result*** reference param could be changed anywhere within the function and it could get hard/messy to track in larger functions).

```
void createSometing(SomeClass& result){
    SomeClass s;
    result = s;

}
```

**Option 3 (return by value - involves copying)**

- **pros**: simple and clear
- **cons**: involves copying an object - which could be expensive. But is this ok?

```
SomeClass createSometing(){
    SomeClass s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is An Answer for this since it would depend on many factors. E.g. how big is an instance of `SomeClass`?

Comment: There are many other options as well, mainly what you choose depends on many options : ownership, cycle of, caching, memory allocators. But in general I expect my factories to return something. (So for me option 2 and 3 are out for that reason alone). If this is all you need then just go for std::make_unique instead of adding another layer (at least you can pass constructor parameters to that)

Comment: Option three would be my suggestion, but it only avoids a copy/move when you function is like `some_type foo() { return some_type(some_parameters); }`.  In your case, `s` would be moved if it can otherwise copied.

Comment: @NathanOliver Named return value optimization is still allowed and I think is usually done.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, it is allowed, but it's not guaranteed so my general advice is to pretend it doesn't get applied unless you actually look at the assembly to confirm.  What can be counted on is all moveable non-static function local objects will get moved in a return statement instead of copied.

Comment: In option 2 the result reference parameter cannot be changed, as references continually point to the same object they were initialized with. For pointers this would be true except by making the pointer parameter itself constant: "SomeClass* const result" (in comparison to "const SomeClass* result"). So the only thing in option 2, what could be changed, is the object referred to.

Comment: Apart from that, I think you understand well the options and all three could make sense for some cases. Important factors could be performance, your architecture, the behaviour of your result type and also how it is created in createSomething() and how it is used after returning.

Comment: A 4th option would be to write a constructor for/into SomeClass or a derived class from SomeClass. Advantages: Caller can freely choose, where the returned class is directly created: heap, local stack or in member variable or as part of container (vector.emplace). No copying/moving involved. Disadvantages: Dirties SomeClass or class hierarchy (if derived).

Comment: Other (more obscure, but sometimes suitable) options: 1) Caller passes a lamda, which is called with SomeClass by createSomething, in the best case the object is consumed by the inlined lambda and the object creation and destruction is optimized away. Advantages: lambda can receive more parameters, possibly saving complete overhead of creating SomeClass. 2) Pass raw memory pointer (e.g. char*), where createSomething() does a placement new of SomeClass into. Mixture of reference parameter and constructor solution.

Comment: 3) Keep a (somewhat global) array of SomeObject with a usage flag/counter for each and a linked list of free ones. CreateSomething() fills a free one and returns the index. Advantages: No memory allocation overhead.

Comment: Just return by value. The object will be moved, which is generally much cheaper and much simpler than dynamically allocating the object and returning a pointer.

Comment: Option 1 for polymorphic classes, from a factory function that is transferring ownership.  Option 3 for non-polymorphic classes.  Option 2 never.

Comment: @Eljay - why never option 2?

Comment: Option 2 is **inefficient**, because to pass in the reference the object must already have been constructed merely to have the construction overwritten moments later.  Option 2 is **non-idiomatic** C++, because the return value is for returning values (which in C++17 and later are guaranteed to have the eliding optimizations).  Option 2 does not represent the **intent**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern C++, the rule is that the compiler is smarter than the programmer. Said differently the programmer is expected to write code that will be easy to read and maintain. And except when profiling have proven that there is a non acceptable bottleneck, low level concerns should be left to the optimizing compilers.

For that reason and except if profiling has proven that another way is required I would first try option 3 and return a plain object. If the object is moveable, moving an object is generally not too expensive. Furthermore, most compilers are able to fully *elide* the copy/move operation if they can. If I correctly remember, copy elision is even required starting with C++17 for statements like that:

```
T foo = functionReturningT();
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single right answer and it depends on the situation and personal preference to some extent. Here are pros and cons of different approaches.

0. Just declare it

```
SomeClass foo(arg1, arg2);
```

Factory functions should be relatively uncommon and only needed if the code creating the object doesn't have all the necessary information to create it (or shouldn't, due to encapsulation reasons). Perhaps it's more common in other languages to have factory functions for everything, but instantiating objects directly should be the first pick.

1. Return by value

```
SomeClass createSomeClass();
```

The first question is whether you want the resulting object to live on the stack or the heap. The default for small objects is the stack, since it's more efficient as you skip the call to malloc(). With Return Value Optimization usually there's no copy.

2. Return by pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> createSomeClass();
or
SomeClass* createSomeClass();
```

Reasons you might pick this include being a large object that you want to be heap allocated; the object is created out of some data store and the caller won't own the memory; you want a nullable return type to signal errors.

3. Out parameter

```
bool createSomeClass(SomeClass&);
```

Main benefits of using out parameters are when you have multiple return types. For example, you might want to return true/false for whether the object creation succeeded (e.g. if your object doesn't have a valid "unset" state, like an integer). You might also have a factory function that returns multiple things, e.g.

```
void createUserAndToken(User& user, Token& token);
```

In summary, I'd say by default, go with return by value. Do you need to signal failure? Out parameter or pointer. Is it a large object that lives on the heap, or some other data structure and you're giving out a handle? Return by pointer. If you don't strictly need a factory function, just declare it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a loaded question, because the matter involves a decision to create the object on the heap vs not creating it on the heap. In C++, it’s ideal to have objects that can be passed around as values cheaply. std::string is a good example of that. It’s generally a premature pessimization to allocate std::string on the heap. On the other hand, the object you may be creating may be large and expensive to copy. In that case, putting it on the heap would be preferable. But that assumes that a copy would have to take place. By default, the copy is eluded! But also: figure out if the type could be made cheaper to copy.

So there’s no “one way suits all”. In my experience, legacy code tends to overuse the heap.

In most cases, returning by value is preferable, since all mainstream compilers will have the function instantiate the object in the storage where it’ll reside, without moves nor copies.

Then, the object can be copy-constructed on the heap by the user of the function, if they so desire, and the compiler will get rid of that copy as well.

Micromanagement of this stuff, without looking at actual generated code, is typically a waste of time, since the code declares intent and not the implementation. Compilers these days literally produce code that has equivalent meaning, taking the C++ source’s semantics, but not necessarily using the source to dictate identical implementation at the machine level.

Thus, in most instances, returning by value is the sensible default, unless the type is borked and doesn’t support that. Unfortunately , some widely used types are in this camp, eg. Qt’s QObject.

TL;DR: Given `MyType myFactoryFunction();`, the statement `auto obj = std::make_unique<MyType>(myFactoryFunction());` will not copy nor move on modern compilers in the release build, if the type is designed well.

Comment: `auto obj = std::make_unique<MyType>(myFactoryFunction());` needs to call the move/copy constructor once to construct the `new`ed object from the temporary. (Of course optimization may make that irrelevant if `myFactoryFunction` can be inlined.)